# Iphone creates symbolic file during crash

Tags: iphone

```
      Any one help to locate symbolic file.Thanks in advance.
```

Regards,
Arunkumar.P

Answer (score 0):

See "Acquiring Crash Reports" section of this [Tech note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html)

Comment: What is mean by symbolic file?

Comment: the file containing debug symbols - its name something like YourAppName.app.dSYM and it is located in the same build folder with your app bundle

Comment: hm, read the tech note carefully - it explains what files you need. Crash log is saved in *.crash file - it's just plain text and you can read it with any text viewer. If your binary has stripped debug symbols then to see readable stack trace you'll need to symbolicate report - the process is described in the note as well

Comment: can you tell about tech note means.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a crash log?  If so, open Xcode, select "Organizer" from the "Window" menu, and find your device.  You'll see a crash log tab.

Comment: What is mean by symbolic file?

Comment: See Vladimir's comment above.